# Is there a de facto standard documentor for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, documentation, documentation-generation, standardization

I'm trying to document my code using JSDOC3, that has a similar syntax to PHPDocumentator / Apigen. But is there a de-facto standard for Javascript inline documentation? I think Google Closure is the most complete (or so it seems), but what is widely adopted by IDEs and what most people expect to the docs to be?

Comment: I don't believe there is. Generally, I don't expect to see docblocks in JavaScript code. The only one I have seen used, though, is JSDoc.

Comment: there really should be a proposal, like they did with PHPDoc, to try and standardize it. Google being 'big' is one step forward, but how many people would follow

Comment: JSDuck works okay. Their docs are pretty poor, ironic, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing which is as big as PHPDoc, but we're using [airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript), which already has over 2.000 stars and more than 350 forks on github, so it's used in a lot of projects.